# Why my function in html code is not being called?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Laravel Livewire project which uses TailwindCSS and AlpineJS. But my issue is about my setCountry() function not being called. I can see the parameters are being correctly passed but the function itself is not being called. The toggleCountriesHandler() function is working nicely.
I bet it is something under my nose, but I still can't figure it out, and I'm a begginer in programming.
Here's my code snippet:

```js
toggleCountriesHandler = () => {
  let toggleCountries = document.getElementById("countriesOpen");
  if (toggleCountries.style.display === "none") {
    toggleCountries.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    toggleCountries.style.display = "none";
  }
}

setCountry = (country_id, country_code, country_name) => {
  document.getElementById("country-id").value = country_id;
  document.getElementById("selected-country").innerHTML = "<img class='w-5 h-5 rounded-full' src='img/flags/16/" + country_code + ".png'>" + "<span class='block ml-3 font-normal truncate'>" + country_name + "</span>";
  document.getElementById("countriesOpen").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.2.0/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<span class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 transform translate-y-5">{{__("Country")}</span>

<div style="height: 42px;" class="relative flex items-center justify-center w-full pl-3.5 pr-10 text-left bg-white border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
  <button onclick="toggleCountriesHandler()" class="block w-full truncate focus:outline-none">
    <label id="selected-country" class="flex flex-row items-center text-gray-500">{{__("Select your country")}}</label>
  </button>
  <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 w-full mt-12 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg sm:bg-white">
    <input id="country-id" type="hidden" name="country_id">
    <ul id="countriesOpen" style="display: none;" class="py-1 overflow-auto text-base rounded-md sm:border max-h-60 ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm">
      @foreach(DB::table('countries')->get() as $country)
      <li role="option" class="relative ">
        <button onclick="setCountry({{ $country->id }}, '{{ $country->code }}', '{{ $country->name }}')" type="button" class="flex items-center w-full py-2 pl-3 space-x-3 cursor-default select-none text-extrading-text-primary sm:text-gray-900 pr-9 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 hover:text-white">
          <img class="w-5 h-5 rounded-full" src="{{ asset('img/flags/16/' . $country->code . '.png') }}">
          <span class="block font-normal truncate">
            {{$country->name}}
          </span>
        </button>
      </li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to declare the variable , for ex `const toggletoggleCountriesHandler=()=>{}`. you missed const

Comment: @SandrinJoy No you don't. Without the keyword, it assigns a global variable.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: ok , thanks for the info  @Barmar

Comment: Thank you Mr. @SandrinJoy! It works fine now :)

Comment: ‍♀️‍♂️ you're welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my comment as an answer to close this question.

```
const toggletoggleCountriesHandler=()=>{}
```

`const` is usually used for the function declarations , since people don't change it.
Still you can use `var` , `let` also for declaration